# Shiny app deployment error on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, deployment, shinyapps

I am trying to deploy shiny app on shinyapps.io but keep getting the error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Timing stopped at: 0.01 0 0.57
Execution halted
```

What is the reason for it and how I can fix it?

I tried to change proxy but it didn't help

Comment: Too little information to know much. How did you push? Have you successfully pushed before? Is your shiny app working locally?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried it at work. I just clicked the push button above the code to publish. I haven't published it before.